# More than one optional argument for newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

The `\newcommand` macro allows to use an optional argument for the first parameter `#1` with:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[3][defaultfor1]{blah blah blah}
```

Is it possible to have more than one option with `\newcommand`?

Comment: No-one said it explicitly, but the answer to the question ``Is it possible to have more than one option with \newcommand?`` appears to be ``No, not without extra packages.``

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try the LaTeX 3 package `xparse`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foocmd}{ O{default1} O{default2} m }{#1~#2~#3}
                            %     ⤷ #1        ⤷ #2    ⤷ #3
\begin{document}
  \foocmd{foo} \par
  \foocmd[nondefault1]{foo} \par
  \foocmd[nondefault2][notfoo2]{foo} \par
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above's LaTeX code]

You may read [the documents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) for more information.

Comment: Agreed - the flexibility with `xparse` even allows for an optional starred `*` version of the command `\foocmd` by using the `s` parameter. See the [`xparse` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf).

Comment: Does that also remove the 9 parameters arguments limit?

Comment: Note that optional arguments defined by `xparse` work properly when nested, so `\foo[[bar]]{stuff}` works to parse `[bar]` as the optional argument. That is not true for `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Raphink No, as the underlying mechanism is still TeX based. We _really_ don't want to encourage >9 arguments for any macro: use keyval input!

Comment: Selecting this answer, since it shows a nice example of `\DeclareDocumentCommand` and egreg already reached rep cap today anyway ;-)

Answer (score 52):

You've got answers for other approaches, so here is the basics using the kernel only. You'll need to define your macros by hand, something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycommand{%
   \@ifnextchar[%
     {\mycommand@i}
     {\mycommand@i[<default-for-1>]}%
}
\def\mycommand@i[#1]{%
   \@ifnextchar[%
     {\mycommand@ii{#1}}
     {\mycommand@ii{#1}[<default-for-2>]}%
}
\def\mycommand@ii#1[#2]#3{%
  % Do stuff
}
\makeatother
```

This can of course be extended to more complex cases. (Here, I'm leaving it up to you whether to make your function `\long` or not. If you want part of it to be long, then all of the internal macros should be long. The `xparse` approach allows this to vary between arguments, based on some internal shuffling.)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I've seen such constructions in some packages already, but I'd really like to avoid it :-)

Comment: I was just writing a solution like this one!

Comment: Well I'd just got to the end of this, and was starting on `twoopt` and `xparse`, when the other two answers popped up :-)

Answer (score 37):

```
\usepackage{twoopt}
\newcommandtwoopt{\xyz}[3][Def1][Def2]{Something with #1, #2 and #3}
```

There are also `\renewcommandtwoopt` and `\providecommandtwoopt`.

However the **xparse** package (part of the LaTeX3 package tree, but works also with LaTeX2e) provides `\DeclareDocumentCommand` that gives great flexibility in defining commands with optional arguments in every position and also *-versions.

*Historical note*

In TeX Live there is a `newcommand.py` Python script accompanied by documentation accessible by `texdoc newcommand`. For example, to obtain code for defining a command with two optional arguments and a mandatory one, one launches

```
python /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/latex/newcommand/newcommand.py
```

and at the prompt `% Prototype:` answers with

```
MACRO twoopt OPT[#1={Def1}] OPT[#2={Def2}] #3
```

where `\twoopt` is the macro we want to define. The script will build a skeleton for defining the macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twoopt}[1][Def1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\twoopt@i[{#1}]}{\twoopt@i[{#1}][{Def2}]}%
}

\def\twoopt@i[#1][#2]#3{%
  % Put your code here.
  % You can refer to the arguments as #1 through #3.
}
\makeatother
```

The commented lines should be replaced by the actual code.

With the specification

```
MACRO finalopt #1 OPT[#2={default}]
```

one defines a macro with a mandatory argument followed by an optional one:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\finalopt}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\finalopt@i{#1}}{\finalopt@i{#1}[{default}]}%
}

\def\finalopt@i#1[#2]{%
  % Put your code here.
  % You can refer to the arguments as #1 and #2.
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @egreg: So `twoopt` is only limited to two optional arguments I guess?

Comment: Yes. See Yan Zhou's answer for more optional arguments.

Answer (score 24):

One more resolution for several optional arguments problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx{\foo}[4][1=defaultFirstArg, 3=defaultThirdArg]{#1~#2~#3~#4}

\begin{document}
    \foo{B}{D}
    \foo[A]{B}{D}
    \foo{B}[C]{D}
    \foo[A]{B}[C]{D}
\end{document}
```

I hope there is nothing to comment here. Also `\renewcommandx`, `\newenvironmentx`, `\renewenvironmentx`, `\providecommandx`, `\DeclareRobustCommandx`, `\CheckCommandx` and their starred versions are available.

Upd. As far as you can see in my example two optional arguments with madatory one in between give you possibility to specify any one of them.

Answer (score 22):

There is a disadvantage using two or more optional arguments. If the user wants to change the default for the second argument, then he must specify the default value of the first argument explicitly. As an example, the optional depth argument of `\raisebox` should be set, but the resulting height should not be changed. That makes the first optional argument cumbersome:

```
\raisebox{-1ex}[\dimexpr\height-1ex\relax][0pt]{foobar}
```

An alternative approach is to design the macro with *one* optional argument exactly, but supporting the key value interface. Nice would be:

```
\raisebox[depth=0pt]{foobar}
```

Also it is easy to define new keys to support new features *without* changing the signature of the command (number and type of options).

There are many packages that support defining and parsing keys (e.g., `keyval` and similar packages, `pgfkeys`, …).

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late on this. Another solution without requiring any additional packages might be:

First we define a command to check whether something is entered:

```
\newcommand{\ifNoWidthThenElse}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox0\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>0pt
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
```

The above is not expandable and checks the width, so entering something, which doesn't produce contents of any width, wouldn't end up as intended. So better would be:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyIfEmtpyTF}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Then we use this command to create our new command:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][]{%
    \MyIfEmptyTF{#2}{\foo}{\bar}%
    #1
}
```

With `\foo` being the command which should be called if leave out the second argument and `\bar` if you use it. This way you can use the first argument as a normal optional argument and the second argument behaves similar to an optional argument but you have to set the `{}`.

Call the function like this:

```
\mycommand[optional1]{optional2}
```

if you use both,

```
\mycommand{optional2}
```

if you use only the second, and

```
\mycommand[optional1]{}
```

if you use only the first.

Comment: There are a couple of things I don’t understand: (1) Why `\setbox1` and not `\setbox0` as the conventions about local vs. global assignments would dictate?  (2) Are you sure you don’t actually mean `\MyIfEmptyTF{#2}{\foo}{\bar{#2}}`?

Comment: @GuM I fixed the `\setbox1`, thanks, when I first wrote this answer I did not know those conventions to be honest. The `\foo` and `\bar` were intended to be anything OP wants, I therefore didn't forward the argument.

Comment: By the way, in LaTeX it's better to do `\sbox{0}{...}` rather than `\setbox0=\hbox{...}`.