# how to define a newcommand with several optional arguments?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More than one optional argument for newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand)

Is it easy to define a new command with several optional arguments, that one would call as follows :

```
\mycom[opt1=2,opt2=blabla]{some arg}
```

Comment: If you mean a keyval argument, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values

Comment: You can also use the package keycommand: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/keycommand

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I suggest you add a suitable answer to the linked question :-)

Comment: I find the version `\command[arg1][arg2]` not optimal, since i will never remember which one is which one, if i want to give only one of them. I will look at the other suggestions.

Comment: well both packages `keyval` and `keycommand` seem to do exactly that...i just have now to choose ! Any suggestion ?

Comment: How about the simpler `kvoptions`? Read [this](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf), especially sections 3.3 and 7.

Comment: @nicolasroy: For very simple commands, just use simplest `keyval`. For more complex macros, see [A big list of every keyval package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package)

Comment: I tried first `\usepackage{keycommand}`, and it is verx eays to use, for my simple command in particular. Thanks for all the suggestions.