# Pass multiple options to \newcommand

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

I have defined a new command for each of the team members in my project group to add individual todo-notes with different color and name.

Now I would like to add another option, but is having trouble with the syntax.

Here is the current definition of the command:

```
% TODO thilemann
\newcommand{\thilemann}[2][ ]
{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{inline}}
    {\todo[inline, size=\small, color=NavyBlue!35]{\textbf{\color{NavyBlue}{Thilemann:} } #2}}
    {\todo[size=\small, color=NavyBlue!35]{\textbf{\color{NavyBlue}{Thilemann:} } #2}}
}
```

How is it possible to add another option to the above code? What I want is basically to define a todo as "mine" which should underline the name (Thilemann:).

I would like the syntax to be something like `\thilemann[mine]{Notes here}` or if it is an inline todo `\thilemann[mine][inline]{Notes here}` (or `\thilemann[mine, inline]{Notes here}`.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand

Answer (score 3):

It would have been easier with a complete document showing which packages you are using (I think this is `todonotes`). Since you are already using a keyval syntax I think I would use the same here so define

```
\define@key{mykeys}{mine}[true]{%
...
}

\define@key{mykeys}{inline}[true]{%
...
}
```

Then in your code activate these with

```
\setkeys{mykeys}{#1}
```

so usage would be

```
\thilemann[mine, inline]{Notes here}.
```

If it is `todonotes` I think that uses the extended `xkeyval` package syntax in which case you should use that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to custom commands and it doesn't seem like I can get the syntax put together the right way :/