# How to create multicolumns list environment with the package 'enumerate'?

Tags: formatting, lists, numbering

Let us consider The following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Which of the following numbers is the largest ?\\
$2^{3^4},2^{4^3},3^{2^4},3^{4^2},4^{2^3},4^{3^2}.$

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item  $2^{3^4}$
\item  $3^{4^2}$
\item  $4^{3^2}$ 
\item $4^{2^3}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]

But I'd like to produce the following using the same package  :
[image]

OR
[image]

OR
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: have you seen [Defining a list environment with multiple optional arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98387) it looks pretty relevant

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but I noticed that even though you have received answers to your questions, you haven't up-voted or accepted any of them (upvoting and accepting are two different actions). Please consider revisiting your questions, upvoting good answers and, in each case, accepting the answer you consider best solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Which of the following numbers is the largest?\\
$2^{3^4}$, $2^{4^3}$, $3^{2^4}$, $3^{4^2}$, $4^{2^3}$, $4^{3^2}$.

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\item  $2^{3^4}$
\item  $3^{4^2}$
\item  $4^{3^2}$ 
\item $4^{2^3}$
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another option, using this time the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and its `inline` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Which of the following numbers is the largest?\\
$2^{3^4}$, $2^{4^3}$, $3^{2^4}$, $3^{4^2}$, $4^{2^3}$, $4^{3^2}$.

\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*),itemjoin={\hspace{\fill}}]
\item  $2^{3^4}$
\item  $3^{4^2}$
\item  $4^{3^2}$
\item $4^{2^3}$
\end{enumerate*}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry,the last answer shows 4 errors one is given here :Environment enumerate* undefined.\begin{enumerate*}. I don't know what is this.

Comment: @SoumitraSen This error indicates that you are using an outdated version of the `enumitem` package. Please update the package (or, even better, your LaTeX system). My second solution works with version 3.5.2 of the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I want to use the second answer but I do not want them all in one line. For example, I want (a) and (b) in one line then below them (c) and (d)?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an ideal task for [`tasks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) (here in combination with [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) which as of May 2017 is superseded by [`xsim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
% this sets up the question headings to be a simple run-in number:
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalfont
}

\usepackage{tasks}
% this creates a new environment `choices' where the single
% choices are indicated with \choice and are labelled (a), (b), ...:
\NewTasks[counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=2em]{choices}[\choice]

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  Which of the following numbers is the largest?\\
  $2^{3^4}$, $2^{4^3}$, $3^{2^4}$, $3^{4^2}$, $4^{2^3}$, $4^{3^2}$.
  \begin{choices}
    \choice $2^{3^4}$
    \choice $3^{4^2}$
    \choice $4^{3^2}$ 
    \choice $4^{2^3}$
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which of the following numbers is the largest?\\
  $2^{3^4}$, $2^{4^3}$, $3^{2^4}$, $3^{4^2}$, $4^{2^3}$, $4^{3^2}$.
  % the optional argument in parentheses determines the number of columns:
  \begin{choices}(2)
    \choice $2^{3^4}$
    \choice $3^{4^2}$
    \choice $4^{3^2}$ 
    \choice $4^{2^3}$
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which of the following numbers is the largest?\\
  $2^{3^4}$, $2^{4^3}$, $3^{2^4}$, $3^{4^2}$, $4^{2^3}$, $4^{3^2}$.
  \begin{choices}(4)
    \choice $2^{3^4}$
    \choice $3^{4^2}$
    \choice $4^{3^2}$ 
    \choice $4^{2^3}$
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, your answe shows the error : File 'exsheets.sty' not found.\SetupExsheets.Please, explain what is this.

Comment: @SoumitraSen this means that your TeX distribution is to old and has èxsheets`not yet installed. You'd need to update your distribution