# How do I use enumeration arrayed as in the image

Tags: enumerate

How do I use enumeration arrayed as in the image[image]

Comment: There is a duplicate somewhere but ....

Comment: Is this what you would like to do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex

Comment: This also shows no research effort... :( [tag:do-this-for-me]

Comment: @Werner: it's not that easy, since only the `shortlst` and `multenum` packages can handle correctly regularly spaced horizontal numbering.

Comment: Use you own counter (or just enter the number directly) and use a tabular.

Comment: egreg has many of these, here is an example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98392/21930.

Comment: @Bernard That just means it is not that easy to provide an answer. It does not mean it would be that hard to demonstrate some effort in the question!

Comment: @cfr: Yes but usually one takes a look at packages that more or less tackle similar situations, and if none are found…

Comment: @Bernard But providing a framework document even with just a some content as a regular enumerate so people don't have to start from scratch is a courtesy to those one is asking to help, whether or not it is possible to layout the content in anything like the desired way. That is, a basic MWE would count as making an effort in the minimal sense I had in mind.

Comment: @scaramouche Thanks for the code. I think this one will work for me well enough. But is there any generalization of this code such as 'triplecol' or 'quadra...'?

Comment: Another solutions is to use \makebox[0.49\textwidth]{1. $a=b$} etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `tasks` package (that was part of `exsheets`, but has become a standalone package), you can obtain something that's pretty close to the picture:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{rulecolour}{CadetBlue2}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[italic]{esdiff}
\newcommand\der{\diff{\hphantom{x}}{x}}
\usepackage[condensed]{cabin}
\usepackage[margin = 2.25cm, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{counter-format = tsk[1]., label-offset =0.6667em, label-align = right, item-indent = 1.5em}%
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%
\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries\large}{\thesection}{1em}{\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{#1}}[{\color{rulecolour}\titlerule[1.2pt]}]%
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries\large}{}{0em}{\lsstyle\enspace \MakeUppercase{#1}}[{\color{rulecolour}\titlerule[1.2pt]}]%
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{2\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}


\titleformat{name=\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\lsstyle\color{rulecolour}#1}
\titleformat{name=\subsection, numberless}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0em}{\lsstyle\color{rulecolour}#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{1.5\baselineskip}{.5\baselineskip}

\newcommand\explan[1]{\quad\footnotesize(#1)}

\begin{document}

\section*{Differentiation rules}

\subsection*{General formulas}

\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $ \der(c) = 0 $
    \task $ \der\bigl[cf(x)\bigr]= c f'(x) $
    \task $ \der\bigl[f(x) + g(x)\bigr]= f'(x) + g'(x)$
    \task $ \der\bigl[f(x) - g(x)\bigr]= f'(x) - g'(x)$
    \task $ \der\bigl[f(x)g(x)\bigr]= f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$\explan{Product Rule}
    \task $ \der\biggl[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\biggr]= \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{\bigl[g(x)\bigr]^{2}} $\explan{Quotient Rule}
    \task $ \der\bigl[f(g(x))\bigr]'= f'(g(x))g'(x) $\explan{Chain Rule}
    \task $ \der\bigl[xⁿ\bigr]= n x^{n-1} $ \explan{Power Rule}
\end{tasks}

\subsection*{Exponential and Logarithmic Functions}

\begin{tasks}[resume](2)
    \task $ \der\bigl(e^{x}\bigr) = e^{x} $
    \task $ \der\bigl(a^{x}\bigr) = a^{x}\ln a$
    \task $ \der\ln\abs[\big]{ x}= \frac{1}{x}$
    \task $ \der\bigl(\log_a\abs[\big]{x}\bigr) = \frac{1}{x \ln a}$
\end{tasks}

\subsection*{Trigonometric Functions}

\begin{tasks}[resume](3)
    \task $ \der(\sin x) = \cos x $
    \task $ \der(\cos x) = -\sin x $
    \task $ \der(\tan x) = \sec^{2}x $
    \task $ \der(\csc x) = -\csc x \cot x $
    \task $ \der(\sec x)= \sec x \tan x $
    \task $ \der(\cot x) = -\csc^{2} x $
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]