# LuaTeX: Call a Lua function with two optional arguments

Tags: luatex, optional-arguments

I've read [More than one optional argument for newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand) and I chose the answer with `xargs`. I would like to pass a second optional argument to the Lua function. But the first of the two commented  `\drawLUAline` lines leads to the error:

`./d.tex:39: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/midway {A}' and
 I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Of course, I can here just add the second optional part as I did, but I want to know how to do this right for other cases. And for me the syntax with the double brackets for the optional arguments is not clear.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function print_line (x, y, optA, optB)

  -- optA: yes
  if optA~=[[]] then
    tex.sprint("\\draw["..optA.."] (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

  -- optA: no
  if optA==[[]]  then
    tex.sprint("\\draw (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

 -- optB: yes
 if optB ~=[[]] then
   tex.sprint(""..optB.."")
 end

end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommandx{\drawLUAline}[4][1, 4]{% 
\directlua{print_line(#2,#3,[[#1]],[[#4]])}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) grid (3,4);
\drawLUAline{3}{1};
\drawLUAline[red]{3}{2};
\drawLUAline[blue]{3}{2.5} node[midway]{A};
%\drawLUAline[green]{3}{3}[node[midway]{A}]; 
%\drawLUAline{3}{4}[node[midway]{A}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Wouldn't it be easier/less cumbersome to specify a Lua function with 4 arguments, with tests for args 3 and/or 4 being empty (and supplying default values if the args are indeed empty)? This Lua function would be invoked by a LaTeX macro whose 3rd and/or 4th args could be empty, say, `\drawLUAline{3}{1}{}{}`, `\drawLUAline{3}{2}{red}{}`, and `\drawLUAline{3}{3}{green}{"node[midway]{A}"}`.

Comment: Of course may be there are better ways. But I would like to be able to choose the best way. So I need information about the choices. That's why I asked my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `xargs` does not support nested brackets, so a optional arguments ends at the first `]`.
In your example this means, that for

```
\drawLUAline[green]{3}{3}[node[midway]{A}];
%                                    ^ This bracket ends the argument
```

the second optional argument is `node[midway`. Then the `{A}]` comes after the macro, so TikZ sees `node[midway{A}]` which leads to the error. You could avoid this by writing braces around the argument, so call the macro with

```
\drawLUAline[green]{3}{3}[{node[midway]{A}}];
%                         ^               ^ These "hide" the ].
```

instead.

If you want your macro to accept the argument without these additional braces, you can use `xparse` instead:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function print_line (x, y, optA, optB)

  -- optA: yes
  if optA~=[[]] then
    tex.sprint("\\draw["..optA.."] (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

  -- optA: no
  if optA==[[]]  then
    tex.sprint("\\draw (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

 -- optB: yes
 if optB ~=[[]] then
   tex.sprint(""..optB.."")
 end

end
\end{luacode*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawLUAline}{O{} m m O{}}{% 
\directlua{print_line(#2,#3,[[#1]],[[#4]])}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) grid (3,4);
\drawLUAline{3}{1};
\drawLUAline[red]{3}{2};
\drawLUAline[blue]{3}{2.5} node[midway]{A};
\drawLUAline[green]{3}{3}[node[midway]{A}]; 
\drawLUAline{3}{4}[node[midway]{A}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While this works, there is another problem hidden in this code: Using `[[#1]]` etc. is unsafe. Especially if the argument could end with a `]` or contain `]]` this leads to weird errors. Use normal quotes and `\luaescapestring` instead:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function print_line (x, y, optA, optB)

  -- optA: yes
  if optA~="" then
    tex.sprint("\\draw["..optA.."] (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

  -- optA: no
  if optA==""  then
    tex.sprint("\\draw (0,0) -- ("..x..","..y..")")
  end

 -- optB: yes
 if optB ~= "" then
   tex.sprint(""..optB.."")
 end

end
\end{luacode*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawLUAline}{O{} m m O{}}{% 
\directlua{print_line(#2,#3,"\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{#4}")}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) grid (3,4);
\drawLUAline{3}{1};
\drawLUAline[red]{3}{2};
\drawLUAline[blue]{3}{2.5} node[midway]{A};
\drawLUAline[green]{3}{3}[node[midway]{A}]; 
\drawLUAline{3}{4}[node[midway]{A}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is the meaning of the double braces: `[[#1]]` ?

Comment: @Nik You find more information about the double square brackets at https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html. They mark string literals, similar to quotation marks. In contrast to quotation marks, no escape sequences are interpreted between them and they can be used for multi-line string literals.