Default not working for new command
\newcommand{\initialize}[2][tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in, right=0.75in, left=0.75in]{
    \geometry{#1} 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\setboolean{indent}{false}}{\setboolean{indent}{true}}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{indent}}{}{\setlength\parindent{0pt}}
    % \setlength\parindent{12pt}
  }%

This is a command in my package which I use as like a preamble sort of.
What I care about here is my default for the geometry command, the default does not get used when I use the command:
\initialize[]{}

Any help on how to get my default to work would be great.

In the newcommand [2] demands to pass exactly 2 parameters, i.e. #1 and #2. So compiling \initialize[]{} should result in errors. See here for details https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros // See here for a similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand

I do not get an error when I use the command, is there anything I can provide to make it so that you can pinpoint what could be causing the error?

Code we can compile to reproduce the problem. But \newcommand[2][<default>]{} wants \initialize[]{} as the first argument is optional. I'm surprised it processes the key-values without barfing, but it's actually fine. But an empty argument isn't the same as no argument. I think @MS-SPO just misread it.

It's hard to guess what you're doing without working (or broken) code, but:

\initialize[]{} passes two arguments --- not one. Both arguments are empty. Since both are specified, the default is not used.
Use \initialize{} to invoke the default value.


This was it thanks!

I don't think you're using the right method.
The mandatory argument to \initialize seems just to distinguish whether it's empty or not and it's not used.
Assuming that the initialization should do
\geometry{tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in, right=0.75in, left=0.75in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

you should be better served with
\NewDocumentCommand{\initialize}{sO{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}}{\setlength{\parindent]{0pt}}%
  \geometry{tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in, right=0.75in, left=0.75in,#2}%
}

Thus a call like \initialize will set the intended default, with zero \parindent, whereas \initialize* would set the default geometry and \parindent to 12pt. With
\initialize[tmargin=2in]

you'd override the tmargin in the default, keeping the other values. Similarly for
\initialize*[tmargin=2in]

that would do the same except setting \parindent to 12pt.
